# AWS load balancer route the traffic to different instances based on IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

We want to give more server resources to some enterprise customer. How can we configure our load balancer so that users from certain IP addresses will route to our more high-end servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible with Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs).  ELB is designed to distribute all traffic approximately equally to all of the instances behind it.  It does not have any selective routing capability or custom "weighting" of back-ends.

Given the relatively low cost of an additional balancer, one option is to set up a second one with a different hostname, in front of this preferred class of instances, and provide that alternate hostname to your priority clients.

Otherwise you'll need to use a third party balancer, either behind, or instead of, ELB, which will allow you to perform more advanced routing of requests, based on the client IP, the URI path, or other variables.

A balancer operating behind the ELB seems redundant at first glance, but it really isn't, since the second balancer can provide more features, while ELB conveniently provides the front-end entry point resiliency into a cluster of load balancers spanning availability zones, without you having to manage that aspect.